# componentWillReceiveProps being called on first render in UC browser

Tags: reactjs, react-router, uc-browser

I have an implementation of single page application using React, React router and Redux. It uses universal rendering. 
There is a React component ArticleListComponent which displays a list of news articles. 
On clicking the back button of the mobile browser, the React lifecycle function **componentWillReceiveProps** compares the route from current props and nextProps (shown in snippet below) and data is fetched accordingly.

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    var prevUrlParam = this.props.match.params;
    var nextUrlParam = nextProps.match.params;
    if(prevUrlParam === nextUrlParam) { 
        return;
    }
    // else data fetch for previous page
}
```

According to documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) , **componentWillReceiveProps is called only when the mounted component receives new props**. This holds true for all mobile browsers, **except for UC browser**. 
On UC browser, on first load of the server rendered page, after the component is mounted, componentWillReceiveProps is called and (prevUrlParam === nextUrlParam) is found to be false, causing data to be fetched. 
**Is the React lifecycle functions working differently for different browsers or is this a bug with respect to UC browser?**

Comment: Have you tested your app on other browsers, and its working on them and not in UC browser?

Comment: Yes, This specific scenario arises only in UC browser and iOS Chrome and not in other browsers.